# doctrine many-to-many not working

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I've got the following schema.yml file, but it's just not working correctly. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
ClientPaymentService:
    actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
    columns:
        clientId: integer
        name: { type: string(100), notnull: true, unique: true }
        paymentServiceId: integer
        config: { type: string(4096), notnull: true }
        cardFormatId: integer
    relations:
        Client:
            local: clientId
            foreign: id
            type: many
            foreignType: one
            foreignAlias: Client
        PaymentService:
            local: paymentServiceId
            foreign: id
            type: many
            foreignType: one
            foreignAlias: ClientPaymentService
        CardFormat:
            local: cardFormatId
            foreign: id
            type: many
            foreignType: one
            foreignAlias: ClientCardFormats
        CountryCode:
            class: CountryCode
            refClass: ClientPaymentServiceCountryCode
            foreign: id            # country_code_id also doesn't work
            local: id

ClientPaymentServiceCountryCode:
    columns:
        client_payment_service_id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
        country_code_id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
    relations:
        ClientPaymentService:
            local: client_payment_service_id
            foreign: id
            foreignAlias: ClientPaymentServiceCountryCodes
        CountryCode:
            local: country_code_id
            foreign: id
            foreignAlias: ClientPaymentServiceCountryCodes

CountryCode:
    actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
    columns:
        name: { type: string(100), notnull: true, unique: true }
        code: { type: string(10), notnull: true, unique: true }
    relations:
        ClientPaymentService:
            class: ClientPaymentService
            refClass: ClientPaymentServiceCountryCode
            local: id
            foreign: id        # client_payment_service_id also doesn't work
```

I receive the following error when trying to save something in the admin area:

```
Unknown record property / related component "id" on "ClientPaymentServiceCountryCode"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this association:

```
ClientPaymentService:
.....
    CountryCode:
        class: CountryCode
        refClass: ClientPaymentServiceCountryCode
        foreign: country_code_id         # country_code_id also doesn't work
        local: client_payment_service_id # you must define both directions

ClientPaymentServiceCountryCode:
    columns:
        client_payment_service_id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
        country_code_id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
    // you not have to define relations here

CountryCode:
   ....
        ClientPaymentService:
            class: ClientPaymentService
            refClass: ClientPaymentServiceCountryCode
            local: country_code_id
            foreign: client_payment_service_id
```

I have just follow documentation :
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/ru#relationships:join-table-associations:many-to-many

Comment: Thanks. It's confusing because ClientPaymentService has no `client_payment_service_id` locally. It has an `id`. Anyway, this works, thanks.

Comment: I understand your confusion, this effect disappears after a few many to many models...